# packages installation in Rstudio

Tags: r, package, cran

I have installed Rstudio IDE yesterday only on vmware (OS:Ubuntu) and were able to fetch packages smoothly but today it has stopped working i.e. I am not able to install packages. Infact, packages that are already installed are giving the error as:
warning in install.packages:
package'bit64' is not available (for R version 3.2.1)
Similarly,installation of packages like twitteR, plyr etc are giving same error (they are not installed yet) 
should I reinstall the setup? can anybody immediately tell me what should I do?

Comment: Did you try to change CRAN mirror?

Comment: how should I do that?

Comment: Tools -> Global options -> Packages.

Comment: This is not rstudio related.

Comment: @Pascal: I did what you said and tried to install package 'twitteR'. Its giving "no exit status" at the end. what does this mean? what should I do next?

Comment: @Roman Lustrik: please elaborate your comment

Comment: @Ooorza you're right, I should have kept my mouth shut. :) Reason for editing your question is embedded in the edit.